# I can't click on the submit button

Tags: php, pdo, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<thead>

<th>E-mail</th>  
<th>Web</th>  

</thead>

{% for member in list_of_members %}     

<form method="POST">     

<tbody>    

<tr>

    <!-- E-mail -->

    <td>

    <input style='width: 220px;' type='text' name='set_email' value='{{member.email}}'>        

    </td>

    <input type='hidden' name='member_id' value='{{ member.id }}'>  
    <button type="submit" formaction="/update-seznam-clenu-vyboru" class="btn btn-success" style='margin-top: 0px;'><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>

    </td>

    </form>

</tr>

 </tbody>

{% endfor  %}
```

I have this code, all is working perfect but, i can't click on the button with the result for id#1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 working good, but 1 not. I dont know why :(((

Comment: I must be blind because I can not see you setting the id in the example above.  Please post your entire code, or at least an instance of id=1 and another of id<>1

Comment: i m not very expert but i think i never see something like this in button `formaction="/update-seznam-clenu-vyboru"`

Comment: <input type='hidden' name='member_id' value='{{ member.id }}'>